# Computing number of arrays containing an element in perl

Tags: perl, arrays, hash, tree, intersection

I think I've just been looking at this too long.  I have some data that looks like this:

```
@a = (
    { name => 'ethan', depth => 0 },
    { name => 'victoria', depth => 1 },
    { name => 'stephen', depth => 2 },
    { name => 'christopher', depth => 3 },
    { name => 'isabella', depth => 2 },
    { name => 'ethan', depth => 3 },
    { name => 'emma', depth => 0 },
    { name => 'michael', depth => 1 },
    { name => 'olivia', depth => 2 },
    { name => 'alexander', depth => 3 },
    { name => 'stephen', depth => 1 },
    { name => 'sophia', depth => 0 },
    { name => 'michael', depth => 1 },
    { name => 'ava', depth => 1 },
    { name => 'joshua', depth => 2 }
);
```

This is a simple 'tree' data structure.  Every time 'depth' = 0, that is the beginning of  a new 'tree'.  What I would like to know is in how many of these trees do each of the names appear?  The desired result would be a single hash with the names as the key, and the count as the value.

The kink in this is, if you look closely, the first tree contains the name 'ethan' twice.  Any tree can have any name more than once, but that should only count as 1, since they all occur in the same tree.  However, 'michael' would have a count of 2, since he appears in two different trees.

I can think of a few ways of doing this, but they all involve multiple loops and seem somewhat brute force and inelegant.  Hopefully, someone else out there can come up with a better solution.

Comment: Any particular reason for choosing this structure for representing a tree? I can think of a few slightly more intuitive formats. :)

Comment: It was primarily an output format -- it didn't need much 'tree' functionality, only how far to indent each entry.  I didn't forsee how much more functionality my co-workers would request once I released the tool, or I would've represented it as a tree in the first place.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure about your problem spec -- is this the correct output?

```
  alexander 1
        ava 1
christopher 1
       emma 1
      ethan 1
   isabella 1
     joshua 1
    michael 2
     olivia 1
     sophia 1
    stephen 2
   victoria 1
```

If so, then this code seems to do the job:

```
my @names = (
  # your @a above
);

my (%seen, %count);

for my $entry (@names) {
  if ($entry->{depth} == 0) {
    ++$count{$_} for keys %seen;
    %seen = ();
  }
  ++$seen{ $entry->{name} };
}

++$count{$_} for keys %seen;
print "$_\t$count{$_}\n" for sort keys %count;
```

that is, just keep a tally of names that only gets shuffled into the global count when we reach the root of the tree.

Comment: Doesn't this code miss the 'root' entry in each tree?  I'd think you'd need to say `%seen = ( $entry->{name} => 1 )` rather than `%seen = ()`.

Comment: @coding_hero: Is it?  I don't see where `emma` and `sophia` are counted.

Comment: @cHao - You are correct.  I mostly scanned the lists for the values > 1 to see if he got the point.  I didn't look for every name.

Answer (score 1):

```
%count = ();
for (@a)
{
    %found = () unless $_->{depth};
    my $name = $_->{name};
    unless ($found{$name}) 
    {
        ++$count{$name};
        $found{$name} = 1;
    }
}
return %count;
```

Basically, what we're doing is keeping a hash of the names we've found in the current tree (which is cleared out whenever the tree switches).  If the current name hasn't been found yet, we bump the count and note that we've found it so it won't get counted again til the tree switches again.

Answer (score 1):

Here is one more way:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict; use warnings;

my @data = (
    { name => 'ethan', depth => 0 },
    { name => 'victoria', depth => 1 },
    { name => 'stephen', depth => 2 },
    { name => 'christopher', depth => 3 },
    { name => 'isabella', depth => 2 },
    { name => 'ethan', depth => 3 },
    { name => 'emma', depth => 0 },
    { name => 'michael', depth => 1 },
    { name => 'olivia', depth => 2 },
    { name => 'alexander', depth => 3 },
    { name => 'stephen', depth => 1 },
    { name => 'sophia', depth => 0 },
    { name => 'michael', depth => 1 },
    { name => 'ava', depth => 1 },
    { name => 'joshua', depth => 2 }
);

my @trees;

for my $x ( @data ) {
    push @trees, {} unless $x->{depth};
    $trees[-1]->{ $x->{name} } = undef;
}

my @names = keys %{ { map { $_->{name} => undef } @data } };
for my $name ( sort @names ) {
    printf "%s appears in %d tree(s)\n",
        $name, scalar grep { exists $_->{$name} } @trees;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this is shortest and simplest solution

```
my (%count, %seen);
for my $e (@a) {
  %seen = () unless $e->{depth};
  $count{$e->{name}}++ unless $seen{$e->{name}}++;
}

print "$_ => $count{$_}\n" for sort keys %count;
```

Result:

```
alexander => 1
ava => 1
christopher => 1
emma => 1
ethan => 1
isabella => 1
joshua => 1
michael => 2
olivia => 1
sophia => 1
stephen => 2
victoria => 1
```

Answer (score 0):

The way I'd go about solving this is to use a recursive function that you map over the array. The edge case is is a depth of 0, in which case you return. otherwise, hold on to the root name, incrementing its value in a hash counter, and then recurse into the subtree where you increment that name as long as it doesn't match the root name, then recurse again, etc.

Comment: Little too complicated.  Unless the spec changes, you don't need recursion for this.

Comment: @cHao: Well, it depends on the spec. If the subtrees can themselves contain subtrees then you need to do something at least similar to recursion

Comment: No, it's not that complicated.  Basically what I outlined above.

Comment: Hence "unless the spec changes".  Right now, only 0 means we're in a new tree.

Comment: I misunderstood the OP then. It seemed to imply that the structure could be nested. If it's flat, then no, you don't need recursion.